# Overriding advanced search form to only search a certain category?

Tags: magento2, advanced-search

**Magento 2.3.3**

I overrode the advanced search form (`/vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/view/frontend/templates/advanced/form.phtml`). Now I want to only search a certain category (by id) when the search button is clicked. How can I achieve that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Copy the file

```
/vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/view/frontend/templates/advanced/form.phtml
```

To

```
app/design/Vendor/Theme/Magento_CatalogSearch/templates/advanced/form.phtml
```

Vendor/Theme is the theme your website is using. once done you should be able to customise the form as you want.

Flush magneto cache either via the admin panel or using the CLI

```
bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: That was how to override it, but I need to know how to make it search a certain category only.

Comment: for that you would need to extend the code to include that sort of filter